# Apache Kafka - iOS producer

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache-kafka

Has anyone integrated iOS devices as a producer for kafka ? is there any libraries in Obj-c or i can call same as normal api call. Please help me to how i can integrate apache kafka producer as iOS application.

Comment: For the time being, you can use Franz https://github.com/kellanburket/franz

Comment: But this is still not stable.